# How to create a stack of cubes with text in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

[image]

I'm trying to create a stack of 3-dimensional cubes with text and perspective like above.

I only need to create one cube; I can manage stacking the rest.
I'm having difficulty creating a single cube and getting the text to show correctly on both right and left sides, although I suspect the text requires separate shapes.

This is my best attempt so far, I know, it's pathetic :-)
Tweaking rotations angles is a pain; is there no 'snap' feature normalizing the perspective along standard angles?

Steps I followed in Powerpoint 2010

- New shape -> Square (flat, not dimensional)
- 3-D Format -> Depth, 50pt
- 3-D Rotation -> Preset -> Perspective Relaxed
- Rotation X: 70, Y: 320, Z: 45

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick try assembled from parallelogram forms (insert / forms / standard forms / parallelogram):

[image]

Once I have a box composed of three gradient colored parallelograms, I add two textboxes and use [3D turns](http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/slides-that-pop-using-the-3rd-dimension-on-a-slide-part-ii-3d-rotation/) to adjust them to the box.

Pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key helps to fine-tune object positions. It takes a bit of practice to use the various handles of a parallelogram form to get the size and the [orientation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/rotate-or-flip-a-picture-shape-text-box-or-wordart-HA010354797.aspx) right.

[image]

Finally, I select all objects and group them. This makes it easier to copy the whole box to get a stack of boxes.

Comment: That's awesone, Axel, but can you elaborate the instructions?